# windows10、python2.7でgstreamerを使う場合の手順

Tags: windows-10, python2

`windows10、python2.7`で`gstreamer`を使う場合の手順を教えてください。
`gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86_64-1.14.0.1.msi`をインストール後、`gst-python-1.14.0`で、
必要そうなものをインストールしてみましたが、`pygst`等がなく、`import pygst`でエラーとなります。また、`pygst`を検索しても見つかりませんでした。
どのようにインストールすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: ちょっと追加しました。もうWindowsでは興味をなくされているかもしれませんが、ご覧ください。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと探していますと、ここにたどり着きました。
[gstreamer home 画面](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/)
ここでDownloadの項目をクリックすると、様々なOSの欄が出て来て、[here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/)というところから、msiがダウンロードできるようになっています。おそらく、これと同じものでインストールされることを試みられたのではないでしょうか？（`gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86_64-1.14.0.1.msi`をインストール後と書かれているので。)
  このサイトの中を探索してみると、[Documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/)の項目に入り、[Installing Gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/index.html)から、再度OSを選ぶ場面に行きました。
　Windowsの絵を選びまして、（アイコンで選ぶようになってまして）こちらに、Windows7~10についてのインストールの方法が述べられていました。

すでにUbuntuでされておられるようなので、必要はないかもしれませんが、これでできないというのでは、ドキュメントも意味もないかなと思います。
（以前の投稿）
此処を看られたらいかがでしょうか？

[gstreamer python bindings for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278953/gstreamer-python-bindings-for-windows/21082448#21082448)

最も簡単な方法は、
[ここ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/)から、最新バージョンをインストールすることです。

もし古いgstreamerがどこかに残っていたら、エラーが発生するようです。
**Gst 0.10　SDKとパイソンモジュールのインストール**
1.[ここ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/)からSDKをインストールし、環境変数をセットする。
GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86=..your sdk dir 
GST_PLUGIN_PATH=%GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86%\lib\gstreamer-0.10
Path=%GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86%\bin;%GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86%\lib;%Path%

2.[ここ](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/)からpygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.7をインストールする。

3.pygst.pthファイルをPythonのサイトパッケージディレクトリ内に造る。
..your %GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86% \lib\python2.7\site-packages 
..your %GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86% \lib\python2.7\site-packages\gst-0.10

4.その後、pydocはpygst,gst等のためのドキュメントを見付けることができるようになる。また、VisualStudioのためのパイソンツール内のインテリセンスも動くはず。（完全なデータベースのリビルドとVSのリスタート。)

**Gst 1.0とパイソンモジュールのインストール**
[ここ](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/)からGstreamer 1.0をインストールする。環境変数を確認しセット
GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86=..Gst 1.0 installation dir 
GST_PLUGIN_PATH_1_0=%GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86%\lib\gstreamer-1.0\ 
Path=%GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86%\bin;%GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86%\lib;%Path%

２．上のリンクからpygi-aio-3.10.2-win32_rev14-setupをインストール。そのインストール内のGstreamerとプラグインを含む
3.gi.pthファイルを作る。
%GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86%\bin 
%GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86%\lib
4.site-packages/gnome directory内からすべてを除く。ただし以下は除く。
libgirepository-1.0-1 
libpyglib-gi-2.0-python27-0 
lib directory with the .typelib files 
少しの単純な例は、よく動くようです。
5.VS内のインテリセンスは、gi.repositoryからのインポートのためには動かないよう
6.このようにインストールをテストしてもよい。
python2 -c "import gi; gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0'); from gi.repository import Gst; Gst.init(None); pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('playbin uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm'); pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING); bus = pipeline.get_bus();msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS)"

もしあなたがGstreamer0.10とGStreamer1.0の両方を使うならば、別々の仮想環境を構築するのが良い。.pthファイルを、そのサイトパッケージディレクトリにおくこと。コメントも見てください。

コメントは省略
リンク張るだけではダメなようなので、簡単な訳を引っ張りましたが、本家をたどっていただくのがいいかなと思います。

Comment: 上記のサイトを参考にしてインストール等、試しているんですが、
>>> import pygst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygst
のようなエラーが出るんですよね？
原因がわかりません。

Comment: 役に立つかどうかわかりませんが、ここにも情報がありましたので投げておきます。判断はご自身でしていただけたらと思いmす。[http://mil-o.jp/yb/gstreamer-cerbero/]

Comment: こっちにもありました。えいっ[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064611/issues-importing-gtstreamer-in-python]

Comment: これは違うか。。。[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401318/gstreamer-with-python-2-7-cannot-import-gst/13661971#13661971]

Comment: 何度もすいません。[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907473/cannot-import-gst-in-python/6970067#6970067]

Comment: 今気づいたんですが
..your %GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86% \lib\python2.7\site-packages
..your %GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86% \lib\python2.7\site-packages\gst-0.10
の記述ってGStreamerの下のlibフォルダーの下にpython2.7というフォルダーがないといけないと思いますが、python2.7というフォルダーがないみたいです。

Comment: そうですか。かなりpython2.7の人たちは本家で混乱されているようなので難しいインストールのようですね。インストールの時は、情報量が大切だと思うので何とか手がかりを見付けてください。その\\の間を追っていくのは大切だと思います。確かsite-packagesというのは、pythonが、サードパーティモジュールを入れ込む場所なので、現在python2.7があるライブラリの中に、モジュールが入っていないのが原因かもしれませんね。今たちまちpython2.7が他のライブラリとつかえているのならば、なおさらかもしれません。

Comment: どうもうまくいかないので試しにubuntuにインストールしてみたら、すんなりいきました。

Comment: そうですか。Ubuntuで動けばいいというのであれば、問題ないのですが、それだと質問がWindowsでとなっているので、出来たら質問を変えて自己解答されるのがいいかなと思います。

Comment: Ubuntuですんなりいきすぎて質問にすらならないというのであれば、いっそ質問自体を消されても私は構いません。ですが、あまり消しすぎると問題になるようなのでそこは気を付けてくださいね。また、放っとくと誰かが答えを書いてくれるかもしれませんので、それに期待するのもいいと思います。